Empty names after scraping World indices table using BeautifulSoup
I am trying to scrape the ticker symbol and full name of the index from the World Index table on Yahoo Finance: https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/
This is the code I have currently:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL of the Yahoo Finance world indices page
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/'

# Send HTTP request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for HTTP errors

# Parse the HTML content of the page using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the table containing the indices data
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'W(100%)'})

# Initialize lists to store ticker symbols and names
tickers = []
names = []

# Extract data from the table rows
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:  # Skip the header row
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    ticker = cells[0].text.strip()
    name = cells[1].text.strip()
    tickers.append(ticker)
    names.append(name)

# Create a dataframe using pandas
data = {'Ticker': tickers, 'Name': names}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the dataframe to a CSV file
df.to_csv('yahoo_finance_world_indices.csv', index=False)

print('Data saved to yahoo_finance_world_indices.csv')

and the resulting csv file:
^GSPC,S&P 500
^DJI,Dow 30
^IXIC,Nasdaq
^NYA,
^XAX,
^BUK100P,
^RUT,Russell 2000
^VIX,
^FTSE,FTSE 100
^GDAXI,
^FCHI,
^STOXX50E,
^N100,
^BFX,
IMOEX.ME,
^N225,Nikkei 225
^HSI,
000001.SS,
399001.SZ,
^STI,
^AXJO,
^AORD,
^BSESN,
^JKSE,
^KLSE,
^NZ50,
^KS11,
^TWII,
^GSPTSE,
^BVSP,
^MXX,
^IPSA,
^MERV,
^TA125.TA,
^CASE30,
^JN0U.JO,

I am wondering why some of the names are not output to my CSV file - I've noticed that the names output are also abbreviations / short-form versions of the full name displayed on the actual table.

I am new at web scraping, so I'm not wholly sure what is going wrong here.

Here is an example how you can get ticker + names from the site:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select('a[data-test="quoteLink"]'):
    print(f"{a.text:<30} {a['title']}")

Prints:
^GSPC                          S&P 500
^DJI                           Dow Jones Industrial Average
^IXIC                          NASDAQ Composite
^NYA                           NYSE COMPOSITE (DJ)
^XAX                           NYSE AMEX COMPOSITE INDEX
^BUK100P                       Cboe UK 100
^RUT                           Russell 2000
^VIX                           CBOE Volatility Index
^FTSE                          FTSE 100
^GDAXI                         DAX PERFORMANCE-INDEX
^FCHI                          CAC 40
^STOXX50E                      ESTX 50 PR.EUR
^N100                          Euronext 100 Index
^BFX                           BEL 20
IMOEX.ME                       MOEX Russia Index
^N225                          Nikkei 225
^HSI                           HANG SENG INDEX
000001.SS                      SSE Composite Index
399001.SZ                      Shenzhen Index
^STI                           STI Index
^AXJO                          S&P/ASX 200
^AORD                          ALL ORDINARIES
^BSESN                         S&P BSE SENSEX
^JKSE                          IDX COMPOSITE
^KLSE                          FTSE Bursa Malaysia KLCI
^NZ50                          S&P/NZX 50 INDEX GROSS ( GROSS 
^KS11                          KOSPI Composite Index
^TWII                          TSEC weighted index
^GSPTSE                        S&P/TSX Composite index
^BVSP                          IBOVESPA
^MXX                           IPC MEXICO
^IPSA                          S&P/CLX IPSA
^MERV                          MERVAL
^TA125.TA                      TA-125
^CASE30                        EGX 30 Price Return Index
^JN0U.JO                       Top 40 USD Net TRI Index

